# jquery form validation not working on dynamically added form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to validate a form, part of which contains dynamically added input fields, but the dynamically added fields are not validating for some reason, here is the code I use to append the field to the form,

Javascript:

```
//instantiate form validation
$("#form").validationEngine('attach');

$("#add_friend").live('click', function(){
    var count = $(".friend").size();
    if(count == 4){
        alert("only 4 friends allowed");
    }else{
        //append a friend field to the friend container
        $("[data-custom='refer_container']").append("<div class='friend'>"
            +"<label for='friend_"+count+"'>friend: </label>"
            +"<input type='text' data-custom='name' class='validate[required] text-input' id='friend_name_"+count+"' name='friend_name_"+count+"' />"
            +"<input type='text' data-custom='email' class='validate[required] text-input' id='friend_email_"+count+"' name='friend_email_"+count+"' />"
            +"<div class='delete'></div>"
        +"</div><br />");
    }
    $("#form").validationEngine('attach');
});
```

I am using [this](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) plugin to validate the form, thanx in advance!

Comment: Can you add in your html as well. Thanks

Comment: Please upload your html in jsfiddle or pastebin. Don't dump it here. Also, when you click add_friends, do you get any javascript errors. Try debugging a little in Firebug or Chrome's inspector. Put a breakpoint in the click handler and see if everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to detach first. Otherwise your new inputs aren't included for evaluation. Might check their API for dynamic additions (which would be better than destructing and reconstructing the validation object)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
        <div data-custom='refer_container'></div>
        <input id="add_friend" type="button" value="Add Friend" />
        <input type='text' data-custom='name' class='validate[required] text-input' id="test" name="test" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //instantiate form validation 
    $(function(){
        $("#form").validationEngine('attach');  
        $("#add_friend").live('click', function(){   
            //Must Detach First
            $("#form").validationEngine('detach');  
            var count = $(".friend").size();     
            if(count == 4){         
                alert("only 4 friends allowed");     
            }else{         
                //append a friend field to the friend container         
                $("[data-custom='refer_container']").append("<div class='friend'>"             
                +"<label for='friend_"+count+"'>friend: </label>"             
                +"<input type='text' data-custom='name' class='validate[required] text-input' id='friend_name_"+count+"' name='friend_name_"+count+"' />"             
                +"<input type='text' data-custom='email' class='validate[required] text-input' id='friend_email_"+count+"' name='friend_email_"+count+"' />"             
                +"<div class='delete'></div>"         
                +"</div><br />");     
            }     
            $("#form").validationEngine('attach'); 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Spot on! Yes, you have to detach first, add your fields and then attach again. Worked for me!